# Height attribute doesn't work on images?

Tags: html, css, image

I have a bit of a ridiculous issue here and I must be missing something obvious, but frustration is starting to get the best of me so I hope someone can point out my error.

I want to display thumbnail images that all have the same height. Width is irrelevant. I need them to have the same height.

Why doesn't the following work?

```
<div class='smallpic'><img src='imageurl' height='100px' title='photo' /></div>
```

This is the CSS for the smallpic div class:

```
.smallpic{
    width:120px;
    height:100px;
    margin:2px;
    float:left;
}
```

The correct images are displayed, but instead of having the same height of 100 px, they all fit to the WIDTH of the div for some reason.

This is the page, there are 4 sample images and as you see they all have the same width and different heights!

http://registry.bedbugs.net/United-States/Santa-Rosa/296-bed-bug-report-for-Hillside-Inn

Comment: Try setting the height to `inherit`. And set the height for your div too. That combination should work.

Comment: shouldn't you be setting the width?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, I perceive the thumbnail images on your site all as the same height.

Comment: @SomeshMukherjee No, if you want an img to have the correct width/height proportion, you should only specify either the width or the height.

Comment: @MrLister What I saw on the page was different widths but same height, which would be expected behaviour. So I was just wondering if he wanted to set the width

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Height is the number of pixels in the image

```
<div class='smallpic'><img src='imageurl' height='100' title='photo' /></div>
```

You can also define this in the css

```
.smallpic>img{
    height:100px
}
```

From you description, it sounds like you want them to be of the same width as well

So try:

```
 .smallpic>img{
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
}
```

Comment: And get rid of that nasty `height` in img element. Because HTML is for content. For presentation use CSS.

Answer (score 0):

The `height` attribute expects a number in pixels. `height='100'` would be valid.
Or you can use CSS to explicitly specify pixels, for instance with an inline `style="height:100px"`
But don't mix up the two!

PS using a stylesheet is preferred these days.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the px inside the height attribute of the image:

```
<div class='smallpic'><img src='imageurl' height='100' title='photo' /></div>
```

Comment: I tried height='100', in fact that's what I originally had in the code, but it didn't work so i added the 'px'